# Implementing an "Unintstall app" and "App info" button in an android launcher application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-launcher

As the title says, I'm developing an android application. I have a recyclerview that renders my app list and a context menu with the options "Unintstall app" and "App info". The App Info button should just open up the android settings page of the application itself, where the user can uninstall, clear cache, change permissions etc.

How do I go about to do this? Is it through some method in packagemanager? Do I need any special permissions for this?

Here's the code that handles the context menu selections in my app drawer class:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case 1: // add to favourites in homescreen
                displayMessage("Added to Favourites");
                return true;

            case 2: // show information about app
                return true;

            case 3: // uninstall application
                displayMessage("Uninstalled application");
                return true;

            // delete this later, it's supposed to be an unreachable message
            default:
                displayMessage("You should not be seeing this message");
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

And here is the relevant code in the recyclerview:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
        public TextView appNameTV;
        public ImageView appIconIV;
        public TextView appCategoryTV;
        public LinearLayout appDrawerItemLL;

        //This is the subclass ViewHolder which simply
        //'holds the views' for us to show on each row
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //Finds the views from our row.xml
            appNameTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.applicationNameTextView);
            appIconIV = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.applicationIconImageView);
            appCategoryTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appCategory);
            appDrawerItemLL = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.app_drawer_item);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            int pos = getAdapterPosition();
            Context context = v.getContext();

            Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appsList.get(pos).getPackageName());
            context.startActivity(launchIntent);
            //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), appsList.get(pos).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            menu.add(this.getAdapterPosition(), 1, 0, "Add to Favourites");
            menu.add(this.getAdapterPosition(), 2, 1, "App info");
            menu.add(this.getAdapterPosition(), 3, 2, "Uninstall app");
        }
    }

    public void addApp(AppObject app) {
        appsList.add(app);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES" />
```

Here is a static method to uninstall any package (protected system or device manufacturer apps will not work). User will always be promted to agree so no forced deinstallation is possible.

```
public static boolean deinstallApp(Context appContext,String packageName)
{
    try {
        Uri apkUri = Uri.parse("package:" + packageName);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, apkUri);
        appContext.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("deinstallApp"," error uninstalling. package not found?!");
    }
    return false;
}
```